# Why $\mathcal I(Y_1\cup Y_2)=\mathcal I(Y_1)\cap \mathcal I(Y_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $$\mathcal I(Y)=\{P\in \mathbb C[X_1,...,X_n]\mid \forall y\in Y, P(y)=0\}.$$

Why $$\mathcal I(Y_1\cup Y_2)=\mathcal I(Y_1)\cap \mathcal I(Y_2)\ \ ?$$
To me, 
$$\mathcal I(Y_1\cup Y_2)=\{P\in \mathbb C[X_1,...,X_n]\mid \forall y\in Y_1\cup Y_2, P(y)=0\}=\{P\in \mathbb C[X_1,...,X_n]\mid \forall y\in Y_1, P(y)=0\}\cup \{P\in \mathbb C[X_1,...,X_n]\mid \forall y\in Y_2, P(y)=0\}$$
$$=\mathcal I(Y_1)\cup\mathcal I(Y_2).$$
What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively: think that if a polynomial vanishes on $Y_1\cup Y_2$, it has to vanish both on $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. This is a stronger condition than to vanish on one of them.

Technically: $\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\cup Y_2\right)$ is the set of all polynomials which vanish on $Y_1$ and on $Y_2$. Therefore, if $P\in\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\cup Y_2\right)$, we must have $P\in\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\right)$ and $P\in\mathcal{I}\left(Y_2\right)$, so $\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\cup Y_2\right)\subseteq\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\right)\cap\mathcal{I}\left(Y_2\right)$.

As for the reverse inclusion, if $P\in\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\right)\cap\mathcal{I}\left(Y_2\right)$, then $P$ vanishes on $Y_1$ and on $Y_2$, so it vanishes on $Y_1\cup Y_2$, meaning $P\in\mathcal{I}\left(Y_1\cup Y_2\right)$.